# String Splitting bugs in Java

Tags: java, string

I thought the `subtitleArray`'s length should be only 2 ,containing **www.facebook.com** and **hello**. But no idea why that happened.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to change this:

```
 value.split("|");
```

To:

```
  value.split("\\|");
```

If you want those trailing empty strings included, you need to use String.split(String regex, int limit) with a negative value for the second parameter (limit) like this:

```
 value.split("\\|",-1);
```

Comment: it works, thz. I thought I tried so before I post it.

Comment: that 2nd parameter -1 is for ?

Answer (score 3):

This is because Java's `split` method accept a Regex as an argument, unlike the counterpart in .NET.

If you don't know what Regex is, let me tell you, `|` has a special meaning in Regex. It does not mean the usual `|` literal but instead it means every character or something like that. (I don't know anything, don't believe me. Use a search engine for more precise info on what does | mean in Regex)

But how do you tell Java not to treat something as a special character? Use backslashes! And how do you tell Regex not to treat something as a special character? Use double backslashes! Why? Because a backslash in a Java string is also a special character too.

In short, you need to escape `|` in Regex so the Regex is like this:

```
\|
```

However, `\` is not allowed in Java strings as a literal, so escape that as well! And you end up with

```
 \\|
```

The whole thing is

```
split("\\|");
```

Pretty counterintuitive, huh?

Comment: The `|` character in a regular expressions means "or", i.e. it can be used to match one of multiple options. That's why Java sees `"|"` as "empty string or empty string", which splits *everywhere*.

Answer (score 2):

you need to escape |

```
try with \\|
```

example

```
String test="www.facebook.com|hello";

    System.out.println(test.split("\\|").length);
```

**OUTPUT** 2

Answer (score 2):

the operator `|` is a special character, so we need to escape it.

Few Special operators

```
\.[]{}()*+-?^$|
```

Try escaping using dole slash, `"\\|"` -> `.split("\\|");`

Answer (score 1):

This is because Java [`split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) takes as first argument a `regex` and not a `String`... Thus `|` is interpreted as OR, so what you are asking it to do is split the string with either `""` or `""` and that's why you get each character (and the empty one at the beginning)

(I am a bit late... but Abdelhak's answer should work)

Answer (score 0):

Java Regular Expressions API are better approach instead of split and replace.
the String.split() and String.replace() methods internally use the regular expression apis themselves, 
which can result in performance issues for your application.
Note that call to String.split() creates and compiles a new Pattern object. 
The same is applicable for the String.replace() methods. 
This compiling of a pattern each time can cause performance issues in your program if you call the split() or replace() functions in a tight loop.